# Getting prioritized value in Hashmap Java

Tags: java

I need to pick the most favorite fruit from the priority given in the `HashMap`. What logic can I use to compare the fruits array and priority `HashMap` to get the expected output.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> priorityHash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
priorityHash.put("Apple",1);
priorityHash.put("Orange",2);
priorityHash.put("Mango",3);

String[]  fruits = ["Mango", "Orange", "Apple"];

String favFruit = "";
```

In the above case, `favFruit` should be assigned with the value `Apple`.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show what you have tried, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, really helps clarify what you want to achieve. Also, please define what happens when the array contains a value not in the map, or is this not possible? See [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166).

Comment: Tip : Have a look at streams, and how you might detect the highest priority value in the map.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Heap data structure and how to use that / use cases of Heap. In Java, you have [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) which can be used as a Heap Implementation.